# JSP and Spring Application

Tags: css, spring, relative-path, jsp-tags

In our spring Application in one of the JSP pages, we have a link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
```

When we run the Project in local environment css works but it does not work in different environment

***In the other environment CSS URL being***

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/myapp/css/jquery-ui.css">
```

when we remove the App name(request.getContextPath()) below this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery-ui.css">
```

The css works in the other environment.

***1. ***In Local System, the Below URL is Working perfectly.******

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%request.getContextPath()%>/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
```

When we remove the ContexPath() means the CSS didn't work

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
```

How to handle this issues in local and other environment?

Comment: Please provide URLs that you get in local and different servers using request.getContextPath()

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<link type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/resources/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```